# javapns file not found

Tags: java, push-notification, push, apple-push-notifications

I try to use javaPns to send push notifications to my device, but I get a file not found exception if I try to use a certificate which is not located on my server but on an external server. 
I think this is because javaPns uses

```
new FileInputStream(path)
```

instead of

```
InputStream is = new URL("http://stackoverflow.com/").openStream();
```

is there a way to use an external server without modify the javaPNS code?

THX 4 your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using JavaPNS 2, you can provide an `InputStream` for the keystore (*not just a local file path*).  Simply create an InputStream as you wrote in your question here, and pass it to any JavaPNS method that requires a keystore.  See the library's on-line documentation for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Um... why are you trying to use a certificate from another server?

The whole point of using certificates is to guarantee that the sender is who the say they are, and using a certificate from somewhere else completely defeats that purpose.

It's like asking why I can't get in my front door with my neighbors key.

The cert is very small... If you are trying to scale and don't want the cert in your code, then put the certificate in your database and read it from there.

But hey, I'm not you...

Let's see what the developers say:
http://code.google.com/p/javapns/issues/detail?id=94

Comment: I see your point, but we have a server for saving data, which is behind our firewalls and is just reachable from the "inside". We don't want to save the certificates and other data on the server which is reachable from the internet. This is our structure and I can't get around this. Ok I could save it in the database, this may help. THX